# Jersey Rest can server send a request to client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm working about a server-client system using Rest architecture with jersey.
 My client app can connect to server and get resources but i have two more problem,first is that: client should send parameters to method and this method should return result to client  back. Second problem is, can server connect to client while client is unaware about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your first question if you can connect to your server and get resources. As to the second you should have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230682/atmosphere-jersey-bidirectional-conversation for more information on using comet with Jersey.